# How to grep through all files in a given revision in git?

Tags: git

Let's say I have a git, with a revision/commit with hash `aaaaaaa` in the past, which described a state with three files, `a.txt`, `b.txt`, and `c.txt`.

So, let's say there were more changes and commits, and current HEAD is at commit `bbbbbbb`, which has files `a.txt`, `e.txt` and `f.txt` - in other works, `b.txt` and `c.txt` from earlier have been deleted somewhere along the way.

Now, what I want to do, is search for a phrase in the files as they were in commit `aaaaaa`, and find in which file(s) it occurs.

Typically, I could do:

```
$ git checkout aaaaaaa
$ grep -r 'phrase' .
```

... but, let's say I do *not* want to checkout, and I want to keep my current state at HEAD, that is commit `bbbbbbb`.

Is there a git command, that will allow me to grep through all the files as in commit `aaaaaaa`, while the checked out files are currently at HEAD of `bbbbbbb` - without having to checkout `aaaaaaa`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git grep` takes an optional `tree` argument. So it's this simple:

```
git grep 'phrase' aaaaaaa
```

`-r` and `.` are implied with `git grep`.